# Deja-dup failing to restore from 14.04 to 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04

I upgraded my Dell notebook,and all my files(encrypted) was in Déja-Dup, from the 14.04 LTS to the new 18.04 LTS and when I try to resore my files from a external HD, Deja-Dup say it can't and failed to restore. No messages or techinal data showup.

Please can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Deja Dup, but I use duplicity. (Pretty much the backend for DD).

Did you encrypt the files with a private key? If so, you need that secret key to decrypt the files. Try:

```
gpg --import /path/to/key/key.key
```

Comment: Backup file is from Ubuntu 16.04. Restoring it to Ubuntu 18.04 is possible? I encrypted with password.